# How to get the current Location name as a string , when we know the latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, latitude-longitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve user's current city name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name)

using the following methods i am getting latitude and longitude of the current position

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
  int minutes = decimal * 60;
  double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];
  latLabel.text = lat;
  degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
  minutes = decimal * 60;
  seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
  longLabel.text = longt;
}
```

now i need to get the current location name as a string... but not required on a map, how can i do this, give me some suggestion pls,,,thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this common function and just pass latitude and longitude as argument in this function.

```
-(NSString *)getAddressFromLatLon:(double)pdblLatitude withLongitude:(double)pdblLongitude
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kGeoCodingString,pdblLatitude, pdblLongitude];
    NSError* error;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    locationString = [locationString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    return [locationString substringFromIndex:6];
}
```

and declare this

```
#define kGeoCodingString @"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%f,%f&output=csv"
```

This function will return address of the latitude and longitude you are passing.

Hope It helps.

Comment: i am passing this url and lati.&longi.  http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=23.030000,72.580000&output=csv   and  i am getting 610,0,0,0   so what is this ? i want to get current city name so plz help me

Comment: getting 610,0,0,0 .. API stopped working. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about [Reverse Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).. Use [MKReverseGeocoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382900/how-to-retrieve-users-current-city-name) SO question explains it a bit..

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSString *addressTxt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", 
                                    [placemark subThoroughfare],[placemark thoroughfare],
                                    [placemark locality], [placemark administrativeArea]];
            NSLog(@"%@",addressTxt);
        }    
    }];
}
```

Comment: i can get current loction but i can't get current address and i also get null value. plz help me and guide me

Comment: @AppleMap: there are multiple reasons for this. i) GeoCoder itself doesn't has address of you location. ii)You have to wait for block to complete.then inside placemark dictionary has multiple values , you can check those key values for you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google API to get the address. Probably you have to send lat and long value as parameter.

Use google [reverse geoCoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

sample http call here http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false

Comment: Thanks buddy. +1 for sample call link. I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you will have to use [MKReverseGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated in like iOS 4.0 and later. So he should use CLGeocoder.